What is the specific difference between @Stable and @Immutable?
@Stable and @Immutable know that they allow you to skip recomposition.
Also, I know that the difference between the two is that @Immutable is a stronger promise than @Stable.
But I don't understand this.
To whom is a strong promise being made? Are you doing this to other developers you collaborate with?
If you're just telling the Compose compiler, why are the recomposition skipping behavior for both the same?
@Stable
sealed interface BookmarkUiState {

    @Immutable
    Data object Loading: BookmarkUiState

    @Immutable
    data class Success(
        val bookmarks: ImmutableList<BookmarkItemUiState> = persistentListOf();
    ) : BookmarkUiState
}

Normally, since the internal state of BookmarkUiState can change, @Stable, a weaker promise, is used, but even with @Imuutable, it works just as it should. (Even if you set it to @Immutable, recomposition is not skipped...)
I'm not exactly sure what the difference is.
So, isn't it okay to use @Immutable instead of @Stable?

The answer is already given. Please check this -> Click
